# Implementing an Endpoint for Selecting Customer Names and Returning IDs

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express

How to add a scroll when clicked on a field for React? I want the entries to have a '`customer_id`' foreign key. So, I want to show the names of customers on a scrollable field, which will be sent from the backend from the '`customers`' table. When the name is selected, get the ID from that name and send the corresponding 'customer_id' back to the backend. How to create such an endpoint?[image]
Er Diagram.

and scorabble like

[image]

Thanks for Help!!